# Error Opening Terminal xterm on Windows GitBash

Tags: windows, git-bash, nano

So I have tried a few ways to install Nano to be able to use it through GitBash on Windows 10.

I've tried the .msi way of installing it, tried downloading the zip and put it in C:/Program Files/Git etc, and it currently works in Windows cmd prompt.

But when I try to use it through GitBash, I get this:

```
Error opening terminal: xterm
```

I've not purposely set an environment variable or anything as one of the guides I followed didn't say I had to.

Any thoughts / help?